# How do i host my fullstack application built with {django & react} on Google cloud

Tags: django, reactjs, google-cloud-platform

I created my portfolio website with django and react. I would like to host on Google cloud free account.

Any doc or tutorials link ?

In local host to run python server, we do python manage.py

for js we do npm run dev.

When we host it in Google cloud. How do these two work.

Looked for tutorials in youtube.

Comment: Google search: https://medium.com/@zackliutju/building-react-and-django-web-application-and-deploy-it-on-google-cloud-545f06eb5521

Comment: Thanks for the .link mate.